# Таймер обратного отсчета в виджете

Tags: java, android, android-widgets

Имеется приложение, которое отсчитывает дни до определенного события, в котором есть возможность установить виджет на рабочий экран.

Проблема в том, что виджет отсчитывает неправильное количество дней и обновляется только если перезагрузить телефон или удалить и заново поставить виджет.

вот код виджета:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class WidgetGeo extends AppWidgetProvider {
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTimerClass(context, appWidgetManager), 1, 60000);
    }
    private class MyTimerClass extends TimerTask {
        RemoteViews remoteViews;
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;
        ComponentName thisWidget;
        public MyTimerClass(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager) {
            this.appWidgetManager = appWidgetManager;
            remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.layout_widget_geo);
            thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, WidgetGeo.class);
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Date date1 = new Date();
            Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2016, 06, 27);
            long days = (((calendar.getTimeInMillis()- date1.getTime())/1000))/86400;
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.oSRCD2,"" + days);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews); 
        }
    }
}
```

Лейаут:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@mipmap/backwidget1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/oSRCD2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"


        android:textSize="14sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Провайдер виджета:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="50dip"
    android:minHeight="50dip"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="10000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/layout_widget_geo"
/>
```